# Easy to remember guid

Tags: java, guid, uuid

Is there a block of Java UUID that won't automatically generated?  I would like to define an easy to remember guid inside of my code that will act as a constant.  Something like a null?

Comment: If you want a constant, define a constant.  Leave the guid to the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want is the static method `UUID.fromString(String)`, where the string is a UUID string that you generated previously.

You could also use the null GUID suggested by David Heffernan, either in string form, or constructed using `new UUID(0L, 0L)`.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be how to create a GUID, rather it's about which value to use

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - that's a matter of interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

The null GUID

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need the GUID for, you could just declare a constant value, named `GUID`, with your own choice of value.  It is your responsibility to ensure you do not use the same value more than once